# Change keyword in a file only in the lines that contain another keyword

Tags: sed, osx-yosemite

I have file with lines that start with two possible keywords, `ATOM` and `HETATM`. In some of those lines, there is a second keyword `HOH`, appearing after some other characters. In other lines, there are other 3-character keywords `XXX` like `SOL` instead of `HOH`:

```
ATOM  1231  O  XXX ...
HETATM1232  O  SOL ...
HETATM1233  O  HOH ...
```

What I want to do is to change `HETATM`s to `ATOM` only if `HOH` also appears on the line.

I tried the following:

```
sed -E '/\(HETATM\)\(.*HOH\)/s//\1ATOM/' file
```

which gives the `illegal byte sequence` error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed '/HOH/s/HETATM/ATOM/' file
```

Output:

```
ATOM  1231  O  XXX ...
HETATM1232  O  SOL ...
ATOM1233  O  HOH ...
```

Only in lines which contain `HOH` search `HETATM` and replace by `ATOM`.

Comment: It does give the desired output, but also gives the same error at the end.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't print all the file. It stops at line 14095.

Comment: Ok, I think it was because I have a weird character at that line. When I do `head -n10000 file | sed '/HOH/s/HETATM/ATOM/'` it works fine. Thanks!